# Let $X$ be a subset of the group $G$, then prove that there is a smallest subgroup $S$ of $G$ that contains $X$

Tags: group-theory

> Let $X$ be a subset of the group $G$, then prove that there is a *smallest* subgroup $S$ of $G$ that contains $X$, that is, if $T$ is any other subgroup containing $X$, then $S \subseteq T$.

Comment: Consider the family of all the subgroups that contains $S$. This family is non-empty (why?) and then it intersection is well-defined. Try to showing that this intersection is the desired subgroup.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

The intersection of a family of subgroups is a subgroup.

Answer (score 0):

We denote $M=\{S{\ }\text{subgroup of }G : X \subseteq S\}$.
We have that $M \neq \emptyset$ because $G \in M$.
We have that $\cap_{S \in M}S$ is a subgroup because it is intersection of subgroups and is the smallest subgroup that contains $X$ because if $Z$ is a subgroup of $G$ that contains $X$ we have that $Z \in M$ so $\cap_{S \in M}S \subseteq Z$.